# Delegate from static library iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I can't make delegate work from static library that i build. If I do in separate project it works correctly. Can you please check my code:

`StaticSdk.h`

```
@protocol SdkDelegate;
@interface Sdk : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SdkDelegate> delegate;
+(void)startAction
-(void)taskComplete;
@end

@protocol SdkDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)taskGetDataCompleted:(NSMutableData*)pushedData;
@end
```

`StaticSdk.m`

```
+(void)startAction{
SdkDelegate *sdk = [[SdkDelegate alloc] init];
[sdk.delegate taskGetDataCompleted:dataMy];
}
```

Than I am including this static library to my project and delegate which i specified is not executed.

Project code
`ViewController.h`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SdkDelegate>
-(IBAction) Connect: (id) sender;
@end
```

`ViewController.m`

```
- (void)taskGetDataCompleted:(NSMutableData*)pushedData
{
    [imageView setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:pushedData]];
}
```

Comment: You haven't understood how delegates are used, you need to go and re-read how they are used. Also you are trying to use one in a class method (that is what the + means, why is one + and the other - ? Is that intentional?). So there's a few basic understanding issues you need to sort out, including the basic use of classes and objects. Try and spend a bit of time to walk before you can run.

Comment: I am using class methods in my static library in order to make the call from project. If i make instance method i can't access it and getting exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're failing to compile on:

```
SdkDelegate *sdk = [[SdkDelegate alloc] init];
```

The issue here is that you cannot instantiate a protocol. Instead you have a class adopt that protocol, which it looks like you did correctly with `ViewController`. What you need to do now is assign your instance of `ViewController` to the `delegate` property of your `Sdk` instance, sometime before you call `startAction`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It compiles just ok, simply i can get callback from my static library

Comment: I'm surprised it would compile. There are a few errors there and you definitely wouldn't be able to call `alloc` and `init` on `SdkDelegate`. However, to use the delegate pattern correctly, your delegate property needs to get set to the object that you want to respond to the call, which in this case is your instance of `ViewController`.